# Simple NSString Error - Printing (null)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm having a problem with NSString. I feel like it's a pretty simple thing to figure out but I've been staring at it for a while and just can't seem to get anywhere :/ Your help is highly appreciated!

I defined a class called Painting.
Here is Painting.h:

```
@interface Painting : NSObject {
    NSString *artist;
    UIImage *image;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *artist;
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIImage *image; 

@end
```

Here is Painting.m:

```
@implementation Painting

@synthesize artist, image;

@end
```

In a .h file for a view controller, I create a "painting":

```
Painting *monet;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Painting *monet;
```

Now, in it's .m file, I'm trying to do a very very simple print and it won't work. I get (null) instead of "Monet".

```
monet.artist = @"Monet";
NSString *bob3 = monet.artist; 
NSLog(@"Real artist: %@", bob3);
```

However, this does work (gives me "Monet" instead of (null)):

```
NSString *bob3 = @"Monet"; 
NSLog(@"Real artist: %@", bob3);
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Have you actually create `monet` at any point? e.g. somewhere you should have `[[Painting alloc] init];`

Comment: Wowwwww, ye that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need before:

```
monet.artist = @"Monet";
```

this:

```
monet = [[Painting alloc] init];
```